# TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in defined function

Tags: python, numpy, model

I get this error message 
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '**getitem**'
In my previous model runs the same strategy has worked perfectly,
so I couldnt figure out whats the difference.

```
r = 0.8 
K1 = 100 
K2 = 50 
q = 1 
E = r 
l = 0.5 
d = 100. 
b1 = 0.05 
b2 = 0.05 
p = 50. 
c = 300. 

i = np.arange(0.,1.01,0.01)
OUTX = np.zeros(i.shape[0])

def I_test(r, K1, K2, E, l, d, b1, b2, p, c, q):
    I= (1/b1*(d-p)) + ((K1- E*q*l/r)* E*q*l + (1/b1)* np.log(p/d)) + ((1-np.exp(-b2*E*q*(1-l)*(K2-E*q*(1-l)/r)/b2))) - c - c*E
    return I

for i in np.arange(0,i.shape[0]):
    I = I_test(r, K1, K2, E[i], l, d, b1, b2, p, c, q)
    OUTX[i]= I[i]
```

Comment: where are `r, K1, K2, E[i], l, d, b1, b2, p, c, q` defined?

Comment: added! I get the error in the first line of the loop I = (1/...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the last line should be

```
OUTX[i]= I
```

Answer (score 0):

Itterating over parameter values.

I found the solution myself. The definition in the first row didn´t allow me to call the parameter E so I had to change from i > E. In the last row the index of I must be taken away then the calculation comes out correctly (as commented by Julien).

```
E = np.arange(0.,1.0,0.1)
OUTX = np.zeros(E.shape[0])

def I_test(r, K1, K2, E, l, d, b1, b2, p, c, q):
    I= (1/b1*(d-p)) + ((K1- E*q*l/r)* E*q*l + (1/b1)* np.log(p/d)) + ((1-np.exp(-b2*E*q*(1-l)*(K2-E*q*(1-l)/r)/b2))) - c - c*E
    return I

for i in np.arange(0,E.shape[0]):
    I = I_test(r, K1, K2, E[i], l, d, b1, b2, p, c, q)
    OUTX[i]= I
```

Comment: Any chance you can accept my answer, as it directly addresses the original  question?